# Rewriting the objective function of PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, principal-component-analysis

> Let $X \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ and $V \in \Bbb R^{m\times d}$. Prove that $$
> \mathcal{F}_{\mathrm{PCA}}(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\|y_{i}-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_{j}\right\|_{2}^{2} = \operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T} X\left(I-\frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1 1}^{T}\right) X^{T} V\right]
> $$ where $y_{i} := V^{T} x_{i}$ and $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the vector of all ones.

---

This is how I tried to prove it.

$$\begin{aligned} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\|y_{i} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_{j}\right\|_{2}^{2} &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( V^T x_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} V^T x_j \right) \left( V^T x_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} V^T x_j \right)^T \\ &= \operatorname{Tr}\left[ V^T X \left(I-\frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}\right) X^T V \left(I- \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1^T}\right) \right]\end{aligned}$$

Comment: You should show us your work on proving this first

Comment: I tried to developp the calculs but i didn' get the right formula..

Comment: I modified my question by adding what I tried to do

Comment: I  thought it's the same.

Comment: yeah you are right..

Comment: yeah .this what i tried to do. but i didn't get the right answer. what about the sum of $y_j$,?

Comment: so what i should to do? i didn't see where I can get $\mathbf{1 1^T}$

Comment: unfortunately not. I'm trying but i didn't get anything yet. btw thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left\| {\rm Y} - \frac1n {\rm Y} {\Bbb 1}_n {\Bbb 1}_n^\top \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 = \left\| {\rm Y} \left( {\rm I}_n - \frac1n {\Bbb 1}_n {\Bbb 1}_n^\top \right) \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 = \mbox{tr} \left( {\rm Y} \left( {\rm I}_n - \frac1n {\Bbb 1}_n {\Bbb 1}_n^\top \right) {\rm Y}^\top \right)$$

Comment: I didn't really understand why you  multiply by $\mathbf{11^T}$, and why $\left(\mathrm{I}_{n}-\frac{1}{n} 1_{n} 1_{n}^{\top}\right) \times \left(\mathrm{I}_{n}-\frac{1}{n} 1_{n} 1_{n}^{\top}\right) ^T =\left(\mathrm{I}_{n}-\frac{1}{n} 1_{n} 1_{n}^{\top}\right)$

Comment: Then do pick a matrix $\rm Y$ and right-multiply it by a square matrix of ones, then divide by $n$. On ${\rm I}_n - \frac1n {\Bbb 1}_n {\Bbb 1}_n^\top$, why don't you compute the product yourself?

Comment: yeah . it's okey. it suffices to compute. Thanks a lot. But sometimes we don't have time to do calculs. so how we can know these tricks of linear algebra?

Comment: Note that ${\rm I}_n - \frac1n {\Bbb 1}_n {\Bbb 1}_n^\top$ is a (symmetric) [projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix). Hence, its square is equal to itself. If one recognizes that it is a projection matrix, there's no need to compute anything.

Comment: @mouadlmazini Consider editing your question and showing your solution step by step. My answer is rather succinct.

Comment: But how we con recognizes that is a projection matrix without calculs?

Comment: Orthogonal projectors are of the form ${\rm A} \left( {\rm A}^\top {\rm A} \right)^{-1} {\rm A}^\top$. Now, let ${\rm A} = {\Bbb 1}_n$.